# What is the correct return of BertForMaskedLM?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model, language-model

I'm using huggingface BertForMaskedLM.
For a sentence, I'm getting a 3-dimensional return from BertForMaskedLM.
For example (P,N,V), Here I understand the N is the length of the sentence and V is the vocab size in Bert. But I'm confused about the P. What is exactly the first return of BertForMaskedLM?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer most probably lies in the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/master/en/main_classes/output#transformers.modeling_outputs.MaskedLMOutput). I linked the MaskedLMOutput which is what BertForMaskedLM `forward` method returns.